# Read from os.stdout

Tags: go, logging, io, buffer

I would like to send log information to a socket, to achieve that, I need to first **capture the os.stdout**. I know i could redirect the os.stdout with os.pipe. But is there a way i directly read from os.stdout use bufio.NewReader or bufio.NewScanner?

```golang
func Start() {
   //dataChan := make(chan string)

   outC := make(chan string, 3)
   defer close(outC)
   conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "localhost:9090")

   if err != nil {
       log.Fatal(err)
   }

   fmt.Println("first line!")
   fmt.Println("second line!")
   fmt.Println("third line!")
   // write to channel
   go func() {
       scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdout)
       for scanner.Scan() {
           outC <- scanner.Text() + "\n"
           err = scanner.Err()

           if err != nil {
               log.Fatal(err)
           }
       }
   }()

   // read from channel and print to connection
   go func() {
       out := <-outC

       for {
           conn.Write([]byte(out + "\n"))
       }

   }()

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could read stdout through [os.Pipe](https://pkg.go.dev/os#Pipe)

```golang
    old := os.Stdout
    r, w, _ := os.Pipe()
    os.Stdout = w

    go func() {
        var buf bytes.Buffer
        io.Copy(&buf, r)
        outC <- buf.String()
    }()

    fmt.Println("first line!")
    fmt.Println("second line!")
    fmt.Println("third line!")

    w.Close()
    os.Stdout = old // restore stdout

    for {
        select {
        case out := <-outC:
            conn.Write([]byte("read " + out + "\n"))
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why i can not directly read os.Stdout?

Comment: @Yangyang, Not every file is readable or writeable. `Stdout` is usually a file that can't be read back. It could be writeable.

Comment: Thank you. That's also the answer i have in mind. It just the go compiler didn't complain about that i am reading from a write only file. Kind of strange.

Comment: FYI: there's a potential race condition capturing/restoring `os.Stdout` here, if this is used in a concurrent situation.

Comment: @colm.anseo Thank you. Is there a way to avoid it. I would like to do the redirection in each go routine, then the reader and writer will all be local variables. So the os.Stdout will be redirect in the go routine, still race condition?